# My P2P app freezes when I clicked anything

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets

I am working on my project where I want to make local P2P communication in C# using Sockets and Threads. I am faced with some troubles when I run my code.

I think the problem is inside next while loop

```
while (true) 
{
    try 
    {
        TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse(STD_IP), HOST_PORT);
        listener.Start();
        using (TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient())
        using (NetworkStream nwStream = client.GetStream()) 
        {
            Thread listenerThread = new Thread(() => 
            {
                string message = Receive(nwStream);
                updateBoard(message);
            });
            listenerThread.Start();

            string response = stanje;

            Send(nwStream, response);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception er) 
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Communication error: \n\n" + er.Message + "\n" + er.StackTrace);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you run the code in the main/ui Thread (or what ever it is called in c#)? this could be the cause of the problem. otherwise please give more details about the rest of the program.

Answer (score 5):

`while (true)` is an infinite loop that your posted code has no way of escaping from.